# Target multiple elements, each of which possess the same class

Tags: html, css

So I want to basically do

```
table.mobile, td.mobile, tr.mobile {
    some css
}
```

is there a way to do this without having to specify each element's class?

So something like

```
(table, td, tr).mobile {
    some css
}
```

Comment: You can use `.mobile { some css} ` for this

Comment: Maybe change the name to something more specific and just use ***.myClassName***

Comment: @SuperUser what if i want to reuse the class name?

Comment: @A.Lau Then use some parent context ie. ***.myParentPage .myClassName*** or ***.myCustomerPage .myClassName***

Comment: @Esko I guess I could do that, but I'm still wondering if there's such an option in css.

Comment: I don't think CSS could do this but SCSS or SASS could do that. `table, td, tr  { &.mobile { some css } }`

Comment: @A.Lau Naming is important, why would you even use same name for different meanings? If the classes are for different use, why do they have the same name at all? Or if they have same use, just use the .class-selector. All the possible selectors are listen in the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

Comment: @Esko because they do the same thing (responsive design)? but offsets might be needed for specific elements.

Comment: @A.Lau Your question is infact totally different than what you asked about :) Your question is about how to make css-variations so that you don't have to rewrite css rules on multiple places. I would suggest using variations where ***.mobile*** has the base set of rules and then you have 1 or many variations like ***.mobile--withmargin*** which adds rules or overwrites them. Then just use it with ***class="mobile"*** or ***class="mobile mobile--withmargin"***

Comment: @Esko my question can't really be interpretted any other way given the fact that i even produced an example of what it may look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet. CSS selectors level 4 specifies [:matches()](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#matches) but browsers don't support it yet.

Firefox and Chrome currently support experimental prefixed pseudo-classes `:-moz-any` and :`-webkit-any` so for those browsers, you can write

```css
:-moz-any(table, tr, td).mobile { 
  display:inline-block; 
  border-width: 1px; 
  border-style:solid; 
  padding:3px 
}
:-webkit-any(table, tr, td).mobile { 
  display:inline-block; 
  border-width: 1px; 
  border-style:solid; 
  padding:3px 
}
table { border-color:blue; }
tr { border-color:green; }
td { border-color:red; }
p { border-color:black; }
```

```html
<table class="mobile">
<tr class="mobile">
  <td class="mobile">borders</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p class="mobile">
no border
</p>
```

Comment: good to know that they will be coming in the future. I guess the only real way to achieve this sort of tagging is through LESS/SASS

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
.mobile
{
// put css that are common to all element with class called mobile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*.mobile{
background:#00496d;
color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr height="25" class="mobile">
<td width="33%">TEXT</td>
<td width="34%">TEXT</td>
<td width="33%">TEXT</td>
</tr>
<tr height="25">
<td class="mobile">TEXT</td>
<td>TEXT</td>
<td>TEXT</td>
</tr>
<tr height="25">
<td>TEXT</td>
<td class="mobile">TEXT</td>
<td>TEXT</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="mobile" style="width:100px; height:100px;"></div>
```

Try It Once *.your Classname Or .Classname is possible to Work for your requirement.

Comment: whts the diff b/w *.classname and .classname?

Comment: both are same and equal

Answer (score -1):

```
table,tr,th.mobile{
    some css
}
```